# AnyLogic : An agent was not able to leave the port root.moveToOkParts1.out

Tags: simulation, anylogic

**Logic follow and the problem is described in the image below:**

[image]

**Note:**
when I remove the "moveTo" block model did not through any error. But i want to see agent move toward the service station on 2D animation so I have to use "moveTo" block, which is throwing error.

Kindly help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this as the condition in the selectoutput block:

```
servicePaint.queueSize()+moveToOkParts1.size()<2
```

This because it's always possible for you to have multiple agents in your moveTo block that your selectOutput is not accounting for that will overflow the queue of your service

Comment: For those that did not know, the Delay block does have a queue. This was my problem